# Can we call submit handler of one form into another form?

Tags: 7, forms

Can we call submit handler of one form into another form?

I have two forms say **user profile form** and  **choose membership plan** I want to unset submit function of **choose membership plan** and want to show in **user profile form** and also both forms field must save.

like  multi-step form.

```
 function myform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id === "ms_membership_list_memberships_form") {
     $form['#validate'][] = "_myform_form_submit_handler";
   }
   if($form_id === "user_profile_form") {
     $form['#validate'][] = "_myform_form2_submit_handler";
   }
 }

 function _myform_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
   $form_state['redirect'] = '/user/1/edit';
 }

 function _myform_form2_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
   $form_state['redirect'] = '/ms/checkout';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the page number as argument to your hook_menu()

```
<?php    
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
      'page arguments' => array(2),
    );
    return $items;
  }
```

Then if it is step-one for example, get your subscription plan form, render it then submit.
In the submit function use:

```
 <?php
// Force the form to rebuild. If we do not do this, the value(s) in $form_state['storage'] will be lost
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
//Redirect to step two
$form_state['redirect'] = 'abc/def/2';
```

In step 2 get the user profile so that in the next submission you'll have the data from both forms in the submit function.

Comment: $form_state['redirect'] not redirecting the page in submit function

Comment: Have you passed &$form_state as reference to the submit handler?

Comment: yes i passed it to submit handler ,my problem is page is redirecting to the same page

Comment: i have added the code above where i am doing wrong

Comment: That's the point exactly, you need to call drupal_get_form() to get the user form on the second page. You could also add the page number as a value to the $form_state variable to know which page the user is currently on